# Parse string date Unparseable date java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a String date like :`Mon Dec 28 15:18:16 2021` into some thing like this: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z`. This is my code.

```
public void parseDate(String stringDate) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatRecived = new SimpleDateFormat("Www Mmm dd HH:mm:ss YYYY");
    try{
        Date date = formatRecived.parse(stringDate);
        System.out.println(date);
    }catch (ParseException parseException){
        System.out.println(parseException.getMessage());
    }

}
```

my exception message is `Unparseable date: "Mon Dec 28 15:18:16 2021"`

can you help me pls?

Comment: what format is `Www` or `Mmm` ? (the formats have different meaning being uppercase or lowercase, but NOT the case in the formatted/parsed string) Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), even better, stop using these outdated classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`), the *new* `java.time` package was introduced in Java 8 (some years ago, 2014 - almost 10 years)

Comment: BTW we usually use `yyyy`. Are you aware of difference between `YYYY` and `yyyy`?

Comment: Further to @user16320675, don’t use java.urial.Date, use java.time - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: First and most important piece of advice, stop using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Both were poorly designed and the former notoriously troublesome. For these reasons both were supplanted by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) about a decade ago. So use `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDateTime` from java.time instead. Among its many features it will help you better detect the errors in your format pattern string.

Comment: No matter if using the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` format pattern letters are case sensitive. I haven’t tried, but I would expect `Www` to be understood as one uppercase `W` (week of month as a number) followed by two lowercase `ww` (week in year).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDateTime
        .parse(
                "Tue Dec 28 15:18:16 2021" ,      // Tuesday, not Monday.
                DateTimeFormatter
                        .ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss uuuu" )
                        .withLocale( Locale.US )  // Critical to parsing name of month, day of week, etc.
        )                                         // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
        .toString()                               // Returns a `String`, with text in standard ISO 8601 format.
        .replace( "T" , " " )                     // Returns another `String` object.
```

> 2021-12-28 15:18:16

## Incorrect data

To begin with, your input data is flawed. 2021-12-28 was a Tuesday, not a Monday. So your input example should be:

```
String input = "Tue Dec 28 15:18:16 2021";
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## Define formatting pattern

Let's write a formatting pattern that matches our input.

```java
DateTimeFormatter f =
        DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss uuuu" )
                .withLocale( Locale.US );
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Then parse as a `LocalDateTime`. This class represents a date with time-of-day, but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

## Unzoned to zoned?

Your input string has no time zone or offset. Yet you expect one in your output, where you specify `z`.

This makes no sense. You would have to specify a time zone (or offset) you know was intended for the input data. But you have presented insufficient information to make that happen.

You can apply a `ZoneId` to a `LocalDateTime` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Adjust to UTC by extracting an `Instant`.

## ISO 8601

Otherwise, your desired output text has a format similar to the standard ISO 8601 format used by default in `LocalDateTime#toString`.

> 2021-12-28T15:18:16

You can replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE by doing simple text manipulation. (Or you could define another custom formatting pattern.)

```
String output = ldt.toString().replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code -

```
public void parseDate(String stringDate) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatRecived = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
    try{
        Date date = (Date)formatRecived.parse(stringDate);
        System.out.println(date);
        SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
        String finalString = newFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(finalString);
    }catch (ParseException parseException){
        System.out.println(parseException.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I changed "Www" to "E" and "YYYY" to "yyyy".

Comment: the error persists :(

Comment: Do not catch and swallow the exception you declared to throw! Although I assume that this is done for debugging here …

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. While meant as helpful in my most honest opinion helping users how to use `SimpleDateFormat` is doing them an ill favour since they should not use that class at all and should switch to java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Also running your code on my computer still gives `Unparseable date: "Mon Dec 28 15:18:16 2021"`.